# Does D have a sufficiently expressive type system to make it feasible to work dynamically?

Tags: d, type-systems

Does D have a *sufficiently expressive type system to make it feasible to work dynamically (that is, with multiple classes of values) within a statically typed framework*?

I ask, after reading [Dynamic languages are static languages.](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/dynamic-languages-are-static-languages/) Sample code, if any, is highly appreciated.

Comment: Too abstract question, i think. What exactly do you need? however, D is static-typed language, like C++ - but more powerful.

Comment: @Arlen: I'm not sure, but maybe `Variant` does what you need.

Comment: I don't really like the tone of the article. I wouldn't say dynamic languages are static languages any more than static languages are machine code. Dynamic languages are an abstraction implemented (generally) on top of static languages. It would be entirely possible to implement a dynamic language in native code, or a static language on top of a dynamic framework, or a dynamic language on top of a static language on top of a dynamic language! Language is an abstraction built from primitives, and the primitives can be interpreted however the language dictates. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only use [`std.variant.Variant`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_variant.html) then D is essentially a dynamically typed language. Here's an example of its usage from the library reference page:

```
Variant a; // Must assign before use, otherwise exception ensues

// Initialize with an integer; make the type int
Variant b = 42;
assert(b.type == typeid(int));

// Peek at the value
assert(b.peek!(int) !is null && *b.peek!(int) == 42);

// Automatically convert per language rules
auto x = b.get!(real);

// Assign any other type, including other variants
a = b;
a = 3.14;
assert(a.type == typeid(double));

// Implicit conversions work just as with built-in types
assert(a > b);

// Check for convertibility
assert(!a.convertsTo!(int)); // double not convertible to int

// Strings and all other arrays are supported
a = "now I'm a string";
assert(a == "now I'm a string");
a = new int[42]; // can also assign arrays
assert(a.length == 42);
a[5] = 7;
assert(a[5] == 7);

// Can also assign class values
class Foo {}
auto foo = new Foo;
a = foo;
assert(*a.peek!(Foo) == foo); // and full type information is preserved
```